# Using Character Controls For BGE

Tags: game-engine

I'm relatively new to blender but I am wondering if there is a way to press a button to set a rotation for an object in game logic. For example, press up to look forward, left to look left, right to look right, etc. I'm trying to achieve movement like in the Super Mario 3D games as opposed to steering the character to look in a certain direction

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to parent your camera to the player, like looking over the shoulder, so you get the perspective but also can see the character. You make the player move and rotate using the logic bricks, and the camera follows you. If this is what you want, there are some great YouTube tutorials, and I just finished a maze game like this and I could send you the file. I'm a beginner too. This is the first question I could answer.

Comment: You should check out [BORNCG](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-uQqhpXIQA&list=PLda3VoSoc_TSS7ht07sCt8zDCyAenOG6i)'s YouTube channel. He has BGE tutorials for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution with action:

You create an action with 4 rotation poses e.g. at frame 1 (North), 2 (West), 3 (South), 4 (East).

Then play the according pose dependent on the key:

[image]

**Be aware:** 
This does align to the scene. It does not align to the camera!